# How to iterate over an enum that has custom values?

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum with custom values:

```
enum DaysOfExercise{

   MONDAY ("legs Workout"),
   WEDNESDAY ("back workout"),
   SATURDAY ("running") ;

   private String exercise ; 

   private DaysOfExercise(String exercise){
       this.exercise = exercise ;
   }

   public String getExercise(){
       return this.exercise ;
   }
}
```

I need to add a search feature that returns a `DaysOfExercise` based on an entered exercise name.

I know that there is is the `.values()` method in the Enum to return the list of `DaysOfExercise` values to easily iterate over, but in my case I want to return the embedded values list to compare with what the user has typed in.

Is there any built-in method that could return the list of the enum custom values instead of the enum values?

Note: It is not that I'm stuck with this problem. I can easily solve it with a couple of loops. I'm just looking for an optimized solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) to [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) an array of enum values to a list of strings.

```
List<String> exercises = Stream.of(DaysOfExercise.values())
    .map(DaysOfExercise::getExercise)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```